# BoletoNet | Erro ao gerar arquivo remessa

Tags: boleto, c#

Olá, preciso de ajuda com este problema. É do Boleto.NET e como vi que a comunidade aqui tem muito conhecimento sobre tal, resolvi postar.

O Cógido abaixo ilustra o que estou passando. Preencho todas as variáveis corretamente, mas quando vou gerar o arquivo de remessa dá a seguinte exceção.

> An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in Boleto.Net.dll but was not handled in user code  Additional information: Erro ao gerar arquivo remessa.

Código:

```
        BoletoNet.Boleto boleto = new BoletoNet.Boleto();

        #region SACADO
        Sacado sacado = new Sacado();
        sacado.Nome = "";
        sacado.CPFCNPJ = "";
        sacado.Endereco = new Endereco();
        sacado.Endereco.End = "";
        sacado.Endereco.Bairro = "";
        sacado.Endereco.Cidade = "";
        sacado.Endereco.CEP = "";
        sacado.Endereco.UF = "";
        #endregion

        #region CEDENTE
        Cedente cedente = new Cedente();
        cedente.Nome = "";
        cedente.CPFCNPJ = "";
        cedente.MostrarCNPJnoBoleto = true;
        cedente.Carteira = "16";
        cedente.Endereco = new Endereco();
        cedente.Endereco.End = "";
        cedente.Endereco.Bairro = "";
        cedente.Endereco.Cidade = "";
        cedente.Endereco.CEP = "";
        cedente.Endereco.UF = "";
        cedente.ContaBancaria = new ContaBancaria();
        cedente.ContaBancaria.Agencia = "";;
        cedente.ContaBancaria.Conta = "";
        cedente.Codigo = "";
        #endregion


        // Banco do Brasil
        Instrucao_BancoBrasil instrucao = new Instrucao_BancoBrasil();
        instrucao.Descricao = boletobd.observacaoBoleto.ToString(); 
        boleto.Instrucoes.Add(instrucao);

        EspecieDocumento_BancoBrasil especie = new EspecieDocumento_BancoBrasil("16");
        boleto.EspecieDocumento = especie;


        boleto.DataVencimento = Datetime.Now;
        boleto.DataDocumento = Datetime.Now;
        boleto.ValorBoleto = 50;
        boleto.Carteira = 16
        boleto.NossoNumero = 1000;
        boleto.Sacado = sacado;
        boleto.Cedente = cedente;
        boleto.ModalidadeCobranca = Convert.ToInt16(16);

        boleto.PercMulta = 10;
        boleto.JurosMora = 5;

        #region BOLETO BANCARIO
        BoletoBancario boleto_bancario = new BoletoBancario();
        boleto_bancario.CodigoBanco = 001;
        boleto_bancario.Boleto = boleto;
        boleto_bancario.MostrarCodigoCarteira = false;
        boleto_bancario.MostrarComprovanteEntrega = true;
        boleto_bancario.GerarArquivoRemessa = true;
        boleto_bancario.Boleto.Valida();
        #endregion


        Boletos objBOLETOS = new Boletos();
        objBOLETOS.Add(boleto);


        var memoryStr = new MemoryStream();
        var objREMESSA = new ArquivoRemessa(TipoArquivo.CNAB400);
        objREMESSA.GerarArquivoRemessa("09", new Banco(001), cedente, objBOLETOS, memoryStr, 1000);
```

O erro acontece na última linha.

E o que consegui de informação adicional é: (Porém, todos os meus objetos foram setados.)

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

Para a pergunta não ser tão específica ao Boleto.NET, gostaria de saber como faço para descobrir (se for possível) o que está causando o problema e também se possível qual a solução.

Comment: Este é um dos (infinitos) problemas do Boleto.NET. As *exceptions* geradas não trazem informações relevantes sobre o erro. Só olhando este código vai ser bem difícil te ajudar. Acho que a melhor solução seria baixar os fontes, referenciar manualmente no teu projeto e *debbugar*. Nem de longe parece uma boa solução, mas, é melhor que "dar tiro no escuro".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para deixar registrado aqui e ajudar a comunidade, vou descrever o que fiz para resolver.

Primeiro, com as dicas dos companheiros(as) Jbueno e Taisbevalle, baixei o código do Boleto.Net e debuguei.

Foi preciso criar uma instância da Remessa dentro do boleto.

```
boleto.Remessa = new Remessa();
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 2):

Eu passei por esse problema, para resolver baixei o código no [repositório oficial](https://github.com/BoletoNet/boletonet) e fui debugando para ver o que estava nulo.

Para que o arquivo seja gerado corretamente, todos os dados da conta devem estar preenchidos corretamente. Endereço do sacado deve estar todo preenchido também.

No seu caso está faltando o `sacado.Endereco.Logradouro` e `sacado.Endereco.Email`. O `Logradouro` não pode ser nulo.

Alguns bancos tem algumas particularidades, você precisa ler o manual de cada  um e ver quais são as informações obrigatórias, pois nessa parte a dll falha. Você só consegue saber se debugar o código. Se você estiver gerando um arquivo remessa para o banco Caixa, você precisa ter o setar a propriedade `EspecieDocumento` e o `Remessa.TipoDocumento` do `Boleto`.

```
Boleto b = new Boleto(item.VencimentoDate, item.ValorDec, item.CarteiraStr, item.NossoNumeroStr, cedente);
    b.NumeroDocumento = item.NumeroDocumentoStr.Completa('0', 10);
    b.EspecieDocumento = new EspecieDocumento(conta.IdBanco.CodigoStr.ToInt32()); // Caixa precisa
    b.EspecieDocumento.Codigo = "01";
    b.Remessa = new Remessa();
    b.Remessa.TipoDocumento = "2";
```

Nesse meu exemplo o `b.Remessa.TipoDocumento = "2"` está setado como `2` porque o Banco caixa precisa dessa informação para gerar o arquivo de remessa, sendo que `1` é para cobrança sem registro e `2` para com registro. Lembrando que não existe mais boleto sem registro, então você pode deixar com `2` mesmo. E a Espécie do Documento é Tipo de documento que originou o boleto de pagamento (Exemplo: Duplicata Mercantil, Duplicata de Prestação de Serviço, Nota Promissória).

Comment: Taisbevalle, aproveitando, me esclareça uma dúvida. O NumeroDocumento seria o "nossoNumero"?

Comment: Não, nosso número é um valor que vai incrementando a cada boleto gerado. Já o número do documento é um número de controle da empresa.

Comment: Link interessante: http://www.jrimum.org/bopepo/wiki/Componente/Documentacao/Negocio#NossoN%C3%BAmero

Comment: Obrigado! Aqui o meu caso era exatamente isso!